# How does hydronic heated flooring work with hardwood?

Tags: heating, hardwood-floor, subfloor, hydronic

I'm interested in putting Hydronic heated floors in a small cabin I'm building.  I've done this before with tile but I really want to use hardwood in this cabin.  I've seen it done before.  I don't know how it was installed but it worked well.  A friend of mine recently installed aluminum-clad structural subfloor with pex cutouts which made a tile covered hydronic system relatively easy.  I'm wondering if the same could be done with wood.  I'm assuming it would have to be a floating floor.  For this reason I am a bit skeptical.

Comment: *"assuming it would have to be a floating floor. For this reason I am a bit skeptical."* plenty of floating hardwood floors out there, so this seems like a leap of Fear Uncertainty and Doubt...?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that but even the best floating floor jobs I've seen, end up with issues after a few years.

Comment: Just a quick comment, I have a floating wood floor on hydronic but the pex tubing was installed in light weight concrete. Not sure how a floating floor would work with your materials.  just saying I've had no problems with a floating floor on a hydronic slab, btw, the house is 15 years old now .

Comment: Put pipes into u shaped aluminium plates with the u designed to clamp the pipe. 3/4" oak laid on top. Still works well.

Comment: @SolarMike How did you attach the oak, or is it completely floating?

Comment: @mreff555 "laid on top" so not attached. floor help in place by the walls.

Answer (score 3):

I have traditional oak tongue and groove (not floating) flooring with radiant heat, and it's great! The previous owner, who was a builder by trade, installed the flooring and radiant heat as new construction in 2000.

The floor has one layer of 3/4" plywood installed on floor joists (16" OC) over a full basement. The finish flooring is 3-1/4" wide by 3/4" thick solid oak tongue and groove, factory pre-finished on top. The oak was installed using 1/2" wide heavy staples shot through the groove at an angle. The staples all pop through the plywood by about 1/4". The PEX below doesn't care about all those sharp points, because it was installed after the floor went in, and the installers just stayed clear of the points.

The tubing is 1/2" PEX-A (Uponor) attached with nailed J-hooks to the floor joists about an inch below the floor above. PEX-A has no trouble bending within the space between joists, so each bay contains a PEX loop from the house's centerline, where the manifolds are, out to the exterior sill and back. Each loop from feed manifold to return manifold heats several bays -- not sure how many.

Fiberglass batts fill the joist space below the level of the PEX loops. The batts don't press up on the PEX; there's free space for air circulation. Aluminized bubble sheet insulation is used in a few places where there was no room for batts. The basement was finished with a suspended ceiling.

Winters here have temperatures in the teens (F) most nights. When my dumb thermostat calls for heat, I circulate water at 125F as long as the outdoor temperature is above 0F. When it goes below 0F the circulating water is 130F. This has been fine for as low as -18F.

I've measured the temperature of the floor while in use, and it generally runs just 2 degrees F higher than the air temperature in the room. It doesn't really feel "warm" to bare feet, just "not cold".

I don't see any shrinkage or heat discoloration to the oak flooring, and that's after 22 years.

Room temperatures are very stable. It generally takes about two hours to raise the room temperature one degree, then about one degree per hour after that. If you're the type that likes to ride the thermostat, don't do this, you'll make yourself crazy. This is a set-and-forget (till Spring) kind of heating. But oh-so-comfy.